# How to remove xml header from rest-assured response

Tags: java, xml, rest-assured, hamcrest, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to make some tests for a service which returns xml.The problem is that in response appear both xml content and the xml header with the version. Because of this, when i'm trying to validate with Matcher.hasXPath i reveive wrong result, because it should contain only one root node.

Tried to find a config (eg:SerenityRest.config().getXmlConfig()) but i don't know where to find specific documentation for my problem.

```
actor.should(seeThatResponse(response -> response.body(Matchers.hasXPath(path)))
);
```

The content i want to remove:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```